# Let $p(z)=z^n+a_1 z^{n-1}+...+a_n$ and suppose that $|p(z)|<1$ for $|z|=1$. Show that $p$ has a zero inside $|z|=1.$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p(z)=z^n+a_1 z^{n-1}+...+a_n$ and suppose that $|p(z)|<1$ for $|z|=1$. Show that $p$ has a zero inside $|z|=1.$

*Comments*: I'm trying to use the Rouché's Theorem.
I tried to write the way: $\frac{p(z)}{z^n}= 1 + \frac{a_1}{z} + ... + \frac{a_n}{z^n}$, but I can not put in the hypotheses of the theorem.

Comment: I believe it is inside $|z|=1$.

Comment: $p(z)=1/2$ doesn't have leading coefficient 1.

Comment: $p(z)$ can not assume the value of $\frac{1}{2}$ as the coefficient of the highest degree must be 1. I am grateful for everyone's help, I managed to solve the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have $|p|<1$ on $|z|=1$ because
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} p(e^{i\varphi})e^{-in\varphi}\, d\varphi=
\int_0^{2\pi}(1+a_1e^{-i\varphi}+\ldots + a_ne^{-in\varphi})\, d\varphi = 2\pi ,
$$
but the absolute value of this integral would be $<2\pi$ if you had $|p|<1$.